# How do I store values printed on console as a vector?

Tags: r, loops, vector, repeat

Suppose I have the following code:

```
x <- 1
repeat
{
  x <- x+1
  print(x)
  if (x>10)
  {
    break
  }
}
```

When I run this, the value of x increases by one, and this x value is printed on to the console until the value of x becomes greater than ten. I have all the values I want of x printed on the console. However, I want to store these values as a vector. How would I do this?

Comment: For this case it 's `x <- 2:11` :). A general solution would likely imply `sapply` or `Reduce` but you don't really give enough to design a general case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 x<-1
 vec<-c()
 while(x<11){
   x<-x+1
   vec<-c(vec,x)
 }
 vec
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly modify your code:

```
x <- 1
y <- NULL
repeat
{
  x <- x+1
  print(x)
  y <- c(y, x)
  if (x>10)
  {
    break
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you choose this process to generate such a vector but I follow @Moody_Mudskipper's logic. 
You should use something simple like `x <- 2:11` or `x <- seq(2, 11, by = 1)`.

Have a look at the [seq()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.html) function too